# In Flutter is there any widget for grouping other widgets? like in HTML there is <fieldset> tag?

Tags: html, flutter, dart, widget

I want to group some widgets in a form, but I can't find any.

I tried divider and container widgets. but I want a design like <fieldset> tag design, any on know ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR0JZ.png) this is the design I am looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is an `InputDecorator`. Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 350,
            width: 400,
            child: InputDecorator(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Personalia',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const Row(
                    children: [
                      Text('First name:'),
                      SizedBox(
                          width: 200,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: TextField(),
                          ))
                    ],
                  ),
                  const Row(
                    children: [
                      Text('Last name:'),
                      SizedBox(
                          width: 200,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: TextField(),
                          ))
                    ],
                  ),
                  const Row(
                    children: [
                      Text('Email:'),
                      SizedBox(
                          width: 200,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: TextField(),
                          ))
                    ],
                  ),
                  const Row(
                    children: [
                      Text('Birthday:'),
                      SizedBox(
                          width: 200,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration:
                                  InputDecoration(hintText: 'dd / mm / yyyy'),
                            ),
                          ))
                    ],
                  ),
                  Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Submit')))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]